# Odoo 17 Branches Configuration

Tags: odoo, branch, odoo-17

I’m configuring Odoo enterprise and I’m struggling to set branches properly.

In my case the branches are not legal entities, I need the branches to use different emails and to control the expenses and income better, so invoices should have the legal entity name and perhaps some additional description of the branch that is issuing them, instead on the address I get the name of the branch. Is this possible by default?

I resolved to let the VAT id of the branch empty since it is not different from the parent company. But how can I set that invoices have the proper legal name instead of the branch name and address? I’ve read the documentation but it is a bit sparse regarding that.

I’ve seen some proprietary modules that seem to that but I have been unable to try them…

Is there some trick in Odoo or would I have to extend the invoice templates for example to detect if the branch has a VAT or doesn’t and act accordingly, if it has it’s own VAT invoice from it and if it doesn’t invoice with the parent information and perhaps add some additional information in the invoice naming the branch?